# How do I get this hover CSS3 effect?

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="item">
    <img src="images/gallery/woman-1.jpg" alt="" width="100%" >
    <div class="content">
        <h3>A blog title.</h3>
    </div><!-- /.content -->
</div>
```

Along with the following CSS:

```
.gallery {
    .item {
        width: 33%;
        height: auto;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

I'd like to get this "Creative Zoe" effect on the items from here:

http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/

I've downloaded the source and tried to apply on the items but when I do, nothing works. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is my attempt:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54191672/theme/index.html

I'm pretty stumped and would REALLY like this effect on my project. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: Most likely through CSS3 Transitions and/or jQuery

Answer (score 2):

```css
figure.effect-zoe figcaption {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 1em;
  height: 3.75em;
  background: #fff;
  color: #3c4a50;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 100%, 0);
}
figure.effect-zoe h2 {
  float: left;
}
figure.effect-zoe figcaption > span {
  float: right;
}
figure.effect-zoe p {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8em;
  padding: 2em;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: none;
  font-size: 90%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s;
}
figure.effect-zoe h2,
figure.effect-zoe figcaption > span {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 200%, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 200%, 0);
}
figure.effect-zoe figcaption > span::before {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 10px;
  font-family: 'feathericons';
  speak: none;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.icon-eye::before {
  content: '\e000';
}
.icon-paper-clip::before {
  content: '\e001';
}
.icon-heart::before {
  content: '\e024';
}
figure.effect-zoe h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
figure.effect-zoe:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}
figure.effect-zoe:hover figcaption,
figure.effect-zoe:hover h2,
figure.effect-zoe:hover figcaption > span {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
figure.effect-zoe:hover h2 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
  transition-delay: 0.05s;
}
figure.effect-zoe:hover figcaption > span:nth-child(4) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
figure.effect-zoe:hover figcaption > span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
  transition-delay: 0.15s;
}
figure.effect-zoe:hover figcaption > span:nth-child(2) {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<figure class="effect-zoe">
  <img src="img/14.jpg" alt="img14">
  <figcaption>
    <h2>Creative <span>Zoe</span></h2>
    <span class="icon-heart"></span>
    <span class="icon-eye"></span>
    <span class="icon-paper-clip"></span>
    <p>Zoe never had the patience of her sisters. She deliberately punched the bear in his face.</p>
    <a href="#">View more</a>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```

It looks like you're missing the classes on your html that they use to trigger the effects.

```
<figure class="effect-zoe">
                    <img src="img/14.jpg" alt="img14">
                    <figcaption>
                        <h2>Creative <span>Zoe</span></h2>
                        <span class="icon-heart"></span>
                        <span class="icon-eye"></span>
                        <span class="icon-paper-clip"></span>
                        <p>Zoe never had the patience of her sisters. She deliberately punched the bear in his face.</p>
                        <a href="#">View more</a>
                    </figcaption>           
                </figure>
```

---

They also have a lot of CSS on it that you dont seem to have

```
/*---------------*/
/***** Zoe *****/
/*---------------*/

figure.effect-zoe figcaption {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 1em;
    height: 3.75em;
    background: #fff;
    color: #3c4a50;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}

figure.effect-zoe h2 {
    float: left;
}

figure.effect-zoe figcaption > span {
    float: right;
}

figure.effect-zoe p {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 8em;
    padding: 2em;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: none;
    font-size: 90%;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s;
    transition: opacity 0.35s;
}

figure.effect-zoe h2,
figure.effect-zoe figcaption > span {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    transition: transform 0.35s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,200%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,200%,0);
}

figure.effect-zoe figcaption > span::before {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    font-family: 'feathericons';
    speak: none;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

.icon-eye::before {
    content: '\e000';
}

.icon-paper-clip::before {
    content: '\e001';
}

.icon-heart::before {
    content: '\e024';
}

figure.effect-zoe h2 {
    display: inline-block;
}

figure.effect-zoe:hover p {
    opacity: 1;
}

figure.effect-zoe:hover figcaption,
figure.effect-zoe:hover h2,
figure.effect-zoe:hover figcaption > span {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

figure.effect-zoe:hover h2 {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.05s;
    transition-delay: 0.05s;
}

figure.effect-zoe:hover figcaption > span:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

figure.effect-zoe:hover figcaption > span:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.15s;
    transition-delay: 0.15s;
}

figure.effect-zoe:hover figcaption > span:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
}
```

Comment: I renamed the figures.effect-zoe to .item and the figcaptions to .content though.